# Copying a git repository to atlassian stash?

Tags: git, stash

We would like to move our git repository to an atlassian stash installation. I have created a new and empty repository in stash and from our existing git repository on my local machine I have executed:

```
git push stash-remote refs/remotes/origin/*:refs/heads/*
```

Where I have configured/added the stash-remote in the repository I am standing in. It shows up fine in the stash web interface.

Is that all I need to do to get a complete copy of our git repository into stash so our developer can continue working on the new stash repository?

Answer (score 1):

After setting up a new stash repo, set the origin of your git repository on your local machine. your can get the url from stash as ssh://.. or http://...

```
git remote add origin http://<your stash repo url>
```

Then push your git repo to stash:

```
git push origin master
```

This pushes your entire master branch to stash, including all previous commits. To push all (committed) branches to stash use

```
git push origin --all
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is mirror the repository before pushing:

```
$ git clone --mirror git@example.com/upstream-repository.git
$ cd upstream-repository.git
$ git push --mirror git@example.com/new-location.git
```

This will create a complete copy with all branches and history.